# How do I access the child's fields of an object inside a user defined treeset?

Tags: java, compareto, treeset

```
public class Dog extends Animal implements Comparable<Animal> {
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private boolean isPottyTrained;

public class Frog extends Animal implements Comparable<Animal> {
    private String color;
    private double maxJump;
    private int bugsEatenPerDay;

public class Animal {
    private double weight;
    private double height;
    private double length;
```

I've created a `TreeSet` of type `Animal`. I have 2 children of `Animal` (`Dog` and `Frog`). My goal is to set the natural order of `Dog` class in alphabetical order by its name and `Frog` class to be ordered by its color (in alphabetical order).

```
public int compareTo(Animal o) {
        if (o.getClass().equals(Dog.class)) {
            int temp = this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(o.getClass().getName());
            if (temp == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else if (temp > 0) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        return 0;

    } // I am not even sure what is producing
```

This is the code I've tried in the `Dog` class, but it did not yield any result.

Ideally, I want the code to be something like

```
if (this.name > o.getName()) {
...
}  //pseudocode
```

But I know it's not possible for the parent to access the fields of the children. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: How do you order a dog and a frog?

Comment: @GhostCat hmm? I'm not sure what you mean? I meant printing it in alphabetical order

Comment: What happens when you add a dog and a frog to the same treeset?

Answer (score 0):

If by 'child' you mean subclass, you should be able to access the subclass methods by casting, like so:

```
((Dog) o).getName()
```

This will only work if you cast the less specific class to a more specific class that it implements, otherwise it will throw a ClassCastException.

The complete solution, then, would look like this:

```
public int compareTo(Animal o) {
    if (o instanceof Dog) 
        return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(((Dog) o).getName());
    return 0;
}
```

This solution, however, assumes that everything that is not a dog is equal, so you'll likely want to implement logic for the other animals as well.

You mention that you don't know what the compare function is producing; it's producing a number that means one of the following:

- The object is 'less than' the parameter value (<= -1)
- The object is 'equal to' the parameter value (0)
- The object is 'greater than' the parameter value (>= 1)

This can be used, for instance, to sort a list according to rules you define.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I applied that compareTo method to both Dog and Frog class but it's printing everything from the Dog class but not the frog class?

Comment: The implementation I provided only really works to compare dogs, and assumes that everything else is equal. You need to decide what makes a frog 'less than', 'greater than', or 'equal to' other frogs, dogs, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

```
public int compareTo(Animal o) {

        if (o instanceof Frog) {
            int compare = this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(((Frog) o).getColor());
            if (compare > 0) {
                return 1;
            } else if (compare < 1) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } else if (o instanceof Dog) {
            int compare = this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(((Dog) o).getName());
            if (compare > 0) {
                return 1;
            } else if (compare < 1) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }

        }
        return 0;

    }// end compareTo
```

This is inside Dog class. Same principle apply to the Frog class

Comment: You compare `dog.name` with `frog.color`. Does it make really sense ?

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: I just wanted to display the Dog name or Frog color in alphabetical order and this does the job